# How correctly append to an Array in typescript?

Tags: arrays, angular, typescript, this

I can't figure out what am I doing wrong, But after making a call to an API, I receive the proper response, but I try to push the response to the array I have. but it returns Undefined.

```
export interface CustomerInfo {
  firstName: string;
  middleName: string;
  lastName: string;
  dateOfBirth: Date;

}
```

```
// if the info comes form parent or not
@Input() customerInfo?: CustomerInfo []=[];

// references would be an array of sting, containing 2 id number, somthing like below: 
refrences = ["jack1","ana12"]

// the getCustomerInfo called on ngOnInit like below:
  ngOnIit() {
    //check if indeed the customerInfo is empty
    if (!this.customerInfo) {
      this.getCustomerInfo()
    }
  } 


getCustomerInfo() {
          for (let reference of references) {
          this.customerService.getCustomerInfo(reference).subscribe(
            value => {
              console.log("customer info ", this.customerInfo)
              console.log("this value ", value)
               this.customerInfo.push(value)
            }, error => {
             console.log(error);
            }
          )
        }
```

#Update:
the issue is the value is log correctly which means I receive the correct response, but the customer info log is undefined. and I don't know why?!
The this log includes customerInfo which the value is undefined,

Comment: You code does not contain any `return` statement, so "but it returns Undefined" sounds like the expected result. Please add the code part where you get `undefined`.

Comment: When defining a variable with the question mark that variable becomes optional and default value for optional variables is undefined.

Comment: @Blazorman - "default value on optional variables is undefined" true as long as you do net set a default value manually. The initial value in this code is an empty array (and making the variable optional looks like an error).

Comment: @ChristophLütjen - I actually tried to declare the `customerInfo` same as above and get error that the variable is not declared, am i missing something here?

Comment: Please provide a [mre] that clearly demonstrates the issue you are facing when you run it.  Ideally someone could drop the code into a standalone IDE like [The TypeScript Playground (link here!)](https://tsplay.dev/wX2QVm) and immediately get to work solving the problem without first needing to re-create it.  So there should be no typos, unrelated errors, or undeclared types or values.

Comment: @Blazorman "am i missing something here" .. I don't know, I can't see your code.

Comment: @ChristophLütjen, Thanks for your feedback, I have added the return but still no result. Will add it in the question too

Comment: @Blazorman, yes you are right, I should have explained more what that? is doing there. its updated

Comment: Please understand that it's really impossible to answer your question if you don't add the code part where you really have the undefined value. All we can do here is guessing this starts with the fact that your code is no valid TypeScript (we have to guess that your fragment is part of a class).

Comment: Asker has not done much with the comments. :/ There is not enough information, but my guess is that the Asker expects the array to have the response *synchronously*, while that response is only available when the callback is called. Then it is a duplicate of [How to return the response from an asynchronous call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call).

Comment: `subscribe` and the arrow function passed to it could also hint that the passed function is used as a callback with no intended return value. Whichever process takes care of the invocation of the subscribed callback also needs to assure that the callback's return value gets passed along further.

Comment: @trincot, Thanks for the link read through it. it has a lot of information about the async/await. but here I have a different problem, which is I cant push the response to the customerInfo array that I have declared.

Comment: Sure you can push it. If you output the array *immediately* after the push, you'll see it is in the array. But your function is executed synchronously: it is **not** the callback which gets executed long after `getCustomerInfo` has finished executing. Although your question lacks the necessary details on what exactly you are inspecting as a result, it is quite likely a duplicate problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was here on `ngOnInit`, which I had to check if `this.customerInfo` is Null or undefined; if so, before making a call to the `getCustomerInfo` API, simply make the customer info equal to an empty array, so that when we get the response back from the call, we can push our response to the array:

```
ngOnIit() {
  if (!this.customerInfo?.length) {
    this.customerInfo = []
    this.getCustomerInfo()
  } 
}
```